# Bigger images when sharing a link with facebook

Tags: facebook

please help here, i am struggling to find a way to share a larger image on my pages when new post is made on my blog.. i am using a wordpress site

unfortunately when i share the link of my post on facebook wall it shows v small image with some description in it. it is not nice for me. i want to share only a very big image form the post with the link to the post. like

https://www.facebook.com/mvbay

I want to know how that page posts bigger images without description

Can anyone please help me .. :(

Comment: I think this is more of a Facebook type question. I know that when adding a link on FB, you can edit the site title and description as well as choose from the images that are on a particular page. That being said, it may be worth while to ensure that your meta values are set appropriately in your theme for titles and descriptions.

Comment: I believe you are looking for [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). And if that's the case, the question is [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) here. I voted to migrate to [webmasters.se], but probably there's already solutions for this, search over there first.